# loading google analytics parametrized async page tracking script

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

If I use the google analytics [async site tracking script](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncTracking.html), in the end of head section of my page, everything works as expected:

```
<head>   
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
        _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'test.com']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/title=ied&action=fire']);

        (function () {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();

    </script>
</head>
```

In the fiddler there can be seen 2 requests:

[image]
[image]

For some reason I need the script to be parametrized, so I wrap it within custom `googleAnalytics` function which gets 2 parameters:

```
function googleAnalytics(domain, queryString) {
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
    _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', domain]);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', queryString]);

    (function () {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
}
```

Abowe code has been saved to **GoogleAnalytics.js** file. I loaded it to the page in the head section like below:

```
<head>
    <script src="/script/GoogleAnalytics.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">googleAnalytics('test.com', '/title=ied&action=fire');</script>
</head>
```

But this time fiddler shows only 1 request:

[image]

The [Google Analytics Tracking Code Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna) also shows nothing.
Only **ga.js** script is downloaded but there is no other request which populates data for google analytics report. What is wrong in this approach and how it can be fixed ?

Btw: I need this 2 parameters and the async version of the tracking script.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the your `_gaq` declaration is local in scope. `ga.js` loads, and looks for `_gaq` in the global scope. (Once the script is injected, it no longer has access to the function's scope.)

To fix it, you can either place `var _gaq = _gaq || [];` outside of the function, or you can replace it within the function with this:

```
window._gaq = window._gaq || [];
```

This will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've made this working.

The **GoogleAnalytics.js** looks following:

```
function googleAnalytics(domain, queryString) {        
    _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', domain]);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', queryString]);
}
```

while the head section is as follows:

```
<head>
    <script src="/script/GoogleAnalytics.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);

        (function () {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">googleAnalytics('com.dev.abb.com','');</script>
</head>
```

Regards